# What is the function of "that" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, relative-pronouns

> A touch of a spurred heel made his horse first start and rear, and then bound away; the dog rushed in his traces; all three vanished-
>
> "Like heath **that**, in the wilderness,
>   The wild wind whirls away."
>   (Jane Eyre)

If there's not *that*, the example makes sense to me. Why is *that* put?

Comment: *That* here is the relative pronoun: "heath *which* the wind whirls away*.

Comment: The word *that* is syntactically highly desirable, in that it helps us to easily see the intended sense which would be clearer (if less poetically expressed) as *like heath whirled away by the wild wind in the wilderness*. But it's a couple of lines quoted from a poem based on a [biblical reference](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah+17%3A6&version=KJV), which I think is Too Localised for ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As StoneyB points out, *[that](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that#Pronoun)* is acting as a [relative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun) here, giving a sense like “heath that the wind whirls away” or “heath which the wind whirls away”.

As FumbleFingers points out, the two lines are from a poem: [Fallen is Thy Throne](http://www.poetry-love-poems.com/moore/fallen-is-thy-throne.php) by Thomas Moore
(born 1779, 36 years before Charlotte Brontë).

I don't know the original publication date of *Fallen is Thy Throne*, except that apparently its first wide availability was in Moore's *Sacred Songs* [1] in May or June, 1816.  Thus the “wild wind whirls away” quotation may be an anachronism: I've supposed the time frame of *Jane Eyre* to be ca. 1809 or 1810, based on reference in Chapter XXXII to Scott's *[Marmion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmion_%28poem%29)* (late 1808) as “a new publication”:

> “... I have brought you a book for evening solace,” and he laid on the table a new publication—a poem ...
>   While I was eagerly glancing at the bright pages of “Marmion” (for “Marmion” it was), St. John stooped to examine my drawing. ...

[[1](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/bio/thomas-moore)] *A Series of Sacred Songs, Duetts and Trios, The Words by Thomas Moore, Esqr. The Music, Composed and Selected by Sir John Stevenson*, part 1 (London: J. Power / Dublin: William Power, 1816; Philadelphia: Published by Geo. E. Blake, 1817?); part 2 (London: J. Power, 1824).